# TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len() in python on atom editor

Tags: python-3.x, atom-editor

I ran this code on my atom editor.I want to code for this problem **Your duty is to modify the function so that if an integer is passed as an input, the function should output a message like "Sorry integers don't have length"**

My code on atom(python 3.6) was :-

```
def celsius_to_farhenheit(C):
    if(type(C)=='int'):
        return ("Not possible to find out its length")
    else:
        return (len(C))


print(celsius_to_farhenheit(10))
```

I was shown the following error on compiling this :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(celsius_to_farhenheit(10))
  File "hello.py", line 5, in celsius_to_farhenheit
    return (len(C))
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Thank You

Comment: You need to check isinstance instead of type @AyanSadhukhan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`type(C)` gives you `<class 'int'>`. If you want to use it, you need to do `type(C) is int`, and not `type(C)=='int'`. That condition is not being satistfied in your code, hence it goes into else and tries to do `len(10)` which throws the exception `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`

```
In [7]: c = 10                                                                                                                                                                                                        

In [8]: type(c) is int                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[8]: True
```

From the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type

> class type(name, bases, dict)
>   With one argument, return the type of an object. The return value is a type object and generally the same object as returned by `object.__class__`.
>   The isinstance() built-in function is recommended for testing the type of an object, because it takes subclasses into account.

So according to the docs, the check should be `isinstance(C, int)` [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance), which checks if `C` is of type `int`
So when we use `isinstance`, it will look like

```
def celsius_to_farhenheit(C):
    if (isinstance(C, int)):
        return ("Not possible to find out its length")
    else:
        return (len(C))

print(celsius_to_farhenheit(10))
#Not possible to find out its length
```